# Fetch sso header information in django

Tags: javascript, java, python, django, single-sign-on

I have an Django application which is configured with SSO login.Now all I want is to fetch the header info of it our get method.Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.META` is a *standard Python dictionary containing all available HTTP headers*

i.e) To get `content_type` `request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']`